# Assign the static array to another array

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test_ {
    char *device_name;
    char *path_name;
};

typedef struct test_ test_t;

struct capabilities_ {
    test_t tab[3];
    int enable;
};

static test_t table[3] = {
    { "first",    "john"},
    { "second",    "mike"},
    { "third:",    "vik" },
};

int main()
{
    struct capabilities_ cap;
    //cap.tab = table; ???
    return 0;
}
```

I have a static array with the value, which I want to assign/copy to the same type/sized variable under the structure to table to cap.tab. Could you please help how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it at runtime, you can use user9000's approach, or something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  cap.tab[i] = table[i];
```

Or, convert your tab to use a pointer to test_t instead of array of test_t.

```
struct capabilities_ {
  test_t *tab;
  int enable;
};

int main()
{
  struct capabilities_ cap;
  cap.tab = table;
  printf("%s\n", cap.tab[1].device_name);
  return 0;
}
```

Or, if you are trying to do it at initialization, use one of the following:

```
struct capabilities_ cap = {
  {
    { "first",  "john" },
    { "second", "mike" },
    { "third:", "vik"  },
  },
  1
};
```

Or this,

```
struct capabilities_ cap = {
  {
    table[0],
    table[1],
    table[2],
  },
  1
};
```

Comment: Does the second one compile?

Comment: Yes, the second initialization option compiles. It is awkward, but it compiles.

Comment: Hmmm...the last alternative does compile OK when `cap` is an automatic variable (as in the question); it fails to compile when `cap` is a global variable. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

`memcpy(cap.tab, table, sizeof (test_t) * (sizeof(table) / sizeof(test_t)));`

This is just the same mechanism used in copying a string to another. Since you have the table size known, you can just do:

`memcpy(cap.tab, table, 3 * sizeof(test_t));`

The equivalent method of copying characters is like:

`memcpy(str, str1, sizeof(char) * 4); // copy 4 of str1 into str`

Comment: Don't you need to `malloc` the memory at the target buffer to hold the space for the three pointers which are unallocated at the start?

Comment: Why? It's not a pointer.  And even if it was a pointer, he can just assign it like so `cap.tab = table;`

Comment: I guess it depends on the intention. The `memcpy` you perform copies the pointers to the strings. Thus, any modification of the strings in `table` or in some other `struct capabilities_` would change them in all locations. It's unclear based on "I want to assign/copy to the same type/sized variable under the structure to table to cap.tab" whether the OP wants a new copy of those strings, or just to point to the existing strings, hence my question.

Comment: @Tawnos I think I was unlcear in my post, I didn't mean it would copy the strings in the structure, what I meant is, it is the same mechanism used to copy strings.

Comment: Why that awkward superfluous multiplication and division by `sizeof(test_t)`? That should simply be `sizeof(table)`. And then you don't rely on hard-coded types, which is dangerous.

Comment: @H2CO3 Oh well, I gave this one out just incase he would use an unknown compile-time array size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the strings, and not just the pointer to the strings, you'll need to allocate memory for each string in the target capabilities `struct`. Here is one way to do that

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(table) / sizeof(test_t); i++)
    {
        size_t device_name_length = strlen(table[i].device_name);
        size_t path_name_length = strlen(table[i].path_name);

        size_t target_device_length = device_name_length + 1; // + 1 for null terminator
        size_t target_path_length = path_name_length + 1; // + 1 for null terminator

        cap.tab[i].device_name = (char*) malloc( target_device_length  );
        cap.tab[i].path_name = (char*) malloc( target_path_length );

        strncpy_s(cap.tab[i].device_name, target_device_length, table[i].device_name, device_name_length);
        strncpy_s(cap.tab[i].path_name, target_path_length, table[i].path_name, path_name_length);
    }
```

If you don't care to make a deep copy, you can use the shallow copy mechanism shown by user9000 to just copy the pointers to the strings.

Also, if you use the mechanism above, don't forget to `free` if your capabilities is going to go out of scope and no longer be used :)